# Does Kismac work on MacOSX 10.9+?

Tags: wifi, macos

Hi I am trying to get Kismac working.

I downloaded the r407 version from here (http://trac.kismac-ng.org/wiki/Downloads) but when I scan for networks I get a never ending sceen saying "Loading Apple Extreme card, passive mode".

When I try to use the other versions, I can scan the network but I get not packets with the passive mode.

Does anyone knows how ot make Kismac work on MacOSX 10.9+?

Many thanks for your help

Best

Comment: This is probably off-topic for this site, as it is not about information security, but requesting support for a tool (albeit one that is primarily used for information security). It would be better directed to the support channel for Kismac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kismac is no longer developed. Besides, macs *generally* do not have the wireless chipset that is capable of injecting packets.

A more effective solution would be to create a linux VM (running under Fusion or your chosen VM software), investigate which chipsets are capable of injection, buy one, install the aircrack-ng suite and go from there.